# Workload partition network

Tags: aix

I see on AIX the workload partition wpars are similar to Solaris zones,but there is a difference,on solaris zone i can ping the external network,wpars are by default isolated.
Can i ping the external network with a wpar?I have to put in promisc mode the network
interface on real AIX machine?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solution
The first,more easy is to use the same subnet and the same network if(en0 for example)
But I don't like it,i want a different ip for my testing wpar
so I use this solution
Give a different ip to wpar(10.1.3.4 for example)
and nat it with ipfnat

```
# Natfile
map en0 10.24.23.115/32 -> 0/32


ipnat -v -f /etc/ipnat.conf
```